# SwiftUI: Custom String Type

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've just started learning SwiftUI, so I'm very new to framework and know very little about the Swift language in general. I'm trying to figure out how to define a custom type.

I've got a `@State` variable that can be one of three strings (`"OFF"`, `"ON"`, `"ONCE"`).

This is what I have so far:

```
@State private var mode: String = "OFF"
```

The problem is, I would like to enforce this variable to conform to a "stricter" type instead of simply setting it to `String`.

Something akin to this maybe... (I realise this isn't valid, but I'm coming from a TypeScript world so please forgive me)

```
type Mode = "OFF" | "ON" | "ONCE"

@State private var mode: Mode = "OFF"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an enum instead of string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an `enum`

```
enum Mode: String {
    case on = "ON"
    case off = "OFF"
    case once = "ONCE"
}
```

Enum in Swift are really powerful, check the complete guide here: [Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)

Comment: You're defining the raw value of each of the cases with `= "ON", right?

Comment: Yes, but of course the raw value could be whatever you need